# Why does data fail on edge network on iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone

[image]

Whenever I perform a speed test using edge network or try to send an image via text message or a group text on edge network it fails, even if I have multiple bars. Why does it fail like that? I seem to be able to receive texts. I expect it to be slow, but I do expect it to work.

iPhone 5, iOS 10.3.2

Comment: I don’t know about MetroPCS, but IIRC, AT&T’s Edge network doesn’t support data (or if it does, it really sucks at it - 5 bars won’t even send a webpage request properly)

Comment: Even a modem can download a web page. Why can't something just as slow?

Comment: Edge is about 100kbps at best... a glimmer better than GPRS but not something you could ever rely on for a data connection. Think of it as a 'digital voice' connection, not data.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's fine. I only want to send text messages. Or access app APIs which probably use JSON. I don't use it to surf the web. And I've surfed the web on a modem for a long time and it was fine with ad blockers.